# Where to declare child component?

Tags: angular

I am just learning Angular (7) and I have a question. My program has the following structure:

```
app.component
- Component A
- - Component A.1
```

So the component A.1 is a child component of A. The component A folder is inside the app folder, and the component A.1 folder is inside the component A folder. I put the A.1 component name inside the "declarations" of A, put not inside the declarations of the app.component. Due to that, I get a "Template parse errors  name is not a known element.

When I put the component A.1 also into the declarations of the app.component, the application works and no error occurs.

Why do I have to declare the A.1 component also in the app.component?

I thought it is enough to put the declaration into the parent component.

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customers/customers.component';
//import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers/customers-list/customers-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomersComponent,
//      CustomersListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
        CustomersComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

A module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CustomersComponent }  from './customers.component';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers-list/customers-list.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [ CustomersComponent, CustomersListComponent ],
    exports: [ CustomersComponent, CustomersListComponent ]
})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

Comment: Let it sit at the level of all other components.  The point is modularity.  If it's useful, chances are you will want to use it somewhere else.

Comment: What do you mean by "I put the A.1 component name inside the "declarations" of A"? Is A a module?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I read so as well in the official documentation. However I am watching a tutorial, where they are stacking the files of the components. Does it make any sense?dd

Comment: @DavideBellone Yes, A is a module.

Comment: If the child requires a specific parent, it sits in the parent folder. If not, it's at the same level as app.module and app.component.

Comment: @TheHeadRush But in the case, were it sits in the parent folder: Why do I have to declare the child in the overall app.module?

Comment: @Pearson Because that the highly opinionated `angular` way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component A module add something like this

```
 declarations: [Component A.1],
....
 exports: [Component A.1]
```

hope is helps

**UPDATE:**

remove the   **CustomersComponent** from declarations

and add **CustomersModule** to imports in your app module

Comment: I tried this, but it still needs the Component A.1 in the declarations of the app.component.

Comment: Did you added the parent module to app.module?

Comment: Yes, I have the parent component A in the declarations of the app.module.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Is there maybe a link to the documentation, why this has to be done like this? (I think I know, but an article would be nice.)

Comment: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-modules/ , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> A component must belong to an NgModule in order for it to be available to another component or application. To make it a member of an NgModule, list it in the declarations field of the NgModule metadata.
>   [officiel documentation about component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#description)

You **must** put the declaration of the component in a module and you can declare it only 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

In the CustomersModule:

```
declarations: [ CustomersComponent, CustomersListComponent ],
exports: [ CustomersComponent, CustomersListComponent ]
```

in the AppModule

```
imports: [CustomersModule]
```

note that in the imports array you must specify **only modules**, not components.